# How would you display the manager name from employee table in an SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an employee table that displays the employee number, name, and manager's employee number. I'm trying to create a query that displays the emp name, emp#, manager name and mgr#.

The table looks like this:

```
EMPNO ENAME  JOB       MGR  HIREDATE  SAL COMM DEPTNO 
7839  KING   PRESIDENT -    17-NOV-81 5000 -   10 
7698  BLAKE  MANAGER   7839 01-MAY-81 2850 -   30 
7782  CLARK  MANAGER   7839 09-JUN-81 2450 -   10 
7566  JONES  MANAGER   7839 02-APR-81 2975 -   20 
7654  MARTIN SALESMAN  7698 28-SEP-81 1250 1400 30 
7499  ALLEN  SALESMAN  7698 20-FEB-81 1600 300 30 
7844  TURNER SALESMAN  7698 08-SEP-81 1500 0   30 
7900  JAMES  CLERK     7698 03-DEC-81 950  -   30 
7521  WARD   SALESMAN  7698 22-FEB-81 1250 500 30 
7902  FORD   ANALYST   7566 03-DEC-81 3000 -   20
```

Three of the columns are pretty simple since they are in the table but how would I add the manager name when all I have is the employee number of their manager?

This is what I have so far that only displays the 3 colums

```
select ename as "Employee", empno as "Emp#", mgr as "Mgr#"  from emp;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select 
  emp.ename as "Employee", 
  emp.empno as "Emp#", 
  emp.mgr as "Mgr#",
  m.ename as "Manager"
from 
 emp
  LEFT OUTER JOIN emp m ON
   emp.mgr = m.empno
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
select e.ename ,e.sal, (select s.grade from salgrade s where e.sal between s.losal and s.hisal) empgrade ,e2.ename"mgr", e2.sal mgrsal,
(select s.grade from salgrade s where e2.sal between s.losal and s.hisal) mgrgrade from emp e,emp e2
where e.mgr=e2.empno(+)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select
  e.ename as "Employee",
  e.empno as "Emp#",
  e.mgr as "Mgr#",
  m.ename as "MgrName"
from emp e
join emp m on e.mgr = m.empno
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.ENAME,E.job 
   FROM EMP E 
   JOIN EMP Y 
     ON E.EMPNO=Y.MGR;
```

This will give you distinct employee name who are managers.

Or:

```
SELECT E.ENAME,E.job 
   FROM EMP E 
   JOIN EMP Y 
      ON E.EMPNO=Y.MGR;
```

Or:

```
SELECT E.ENAME,E.job 
   FROM EMP E, EMP Y 
   WHERE 
     E.EMPNO=Y.MGR;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select   e.ename as "Employee",  e.empno as "Emp#",  e.mgr as "Mgr#",  m.ename as "MgrName" from emp e ,  emp m   on e.mgr = m.empno
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT E2.EMPID,E2.EMPNAME,E1.EMPNAME 
AS MGRNAME 
FROM employee E1 
   INNER JOIN employee E2 ON E1.Empid=E2.ManagerId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (CASE 
WHEN e1.manager_id IS NULL THEN
  e1.last_name ||' IS THE PRESIDENT'
ELSE
  e2.last_name || ' IS THE MANAGER OF '||e1.last_name
END)"HIERARCHY" FROM hr.employees e1, hr.employees e2 WHERE e1.manager_id = e2.employee_id(+) ORDER BY e1.manager_id NULLS FIRST
```

Comment: Normally for computational work, we just want the data -- undecorated. UI & decoration should be left to a separate layer -- and you shouldn't process or decorate the nulls!   While doing all those things, your answer has also missed out all the other (useful) columns.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it is working just fine.

```
SELECT a.empno EmpID,a.empname EmpName, a.mgrid MgrID,(select empname from employee where empno = a.mgrid) MgrName 
from employee a, employee b
where a.empno = b.empno order by a.empno asc;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Select e.ename empname , m.ename managername,e.empno empno ,m.mgr managerno from emp e, mgr m
where m.empno=e.mgr
```